# The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type Vb dot net

Tags: vb.net

I am facing the issue in one of my vb dot net application while posting the values to web api method.

My code:

```
Dim uri As String = "http://server/api/TMS/CreateIndent"
Dim request As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
Dim headers As WebHeaderCollection = New WebHeaderCollection()
Dim tokenurl As String = Token

request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data"
request.Method = "POST"
headers.Add("Token", tokenurl)
headers.Add("NTID", "abcdef")
request.Headers = headers

Dim value As String = "[{""PurposeId"" : ""4"",""MitraIndentId"": ""558"",""Employee"":{""NTID"": ""abcdedf""},""Purposeothers"": ""null"", ""TravellingDetails"":[{""ModeOfTravelID"": ""4"",""DepartureDate"":""01/02/2022 16:23"",""DepartedFrom"":""TD1"",""ArrivalDate"":""02/02/2022 16:24"",""ArrivalAt"":""TD2"",""BoschCost"":""123"",""EmployeeCost"":""500"",""IsSupportDocumnentAvailable"":""true"",""DeviationKey"":""1644404033300""}]}]"

Dim array(1) As Char
array(0) = "["
array(1) = " "
Dim value1 As String = value.Remove(value.Length - 1)
Dim value2 As String = value1.TrimStart(array)
Dim keyparameter = New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {
{"Expense", value2}}

Dim PostString As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(keyparameter)
Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PostString)
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
Dim dataStream As IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
dataStream.Close() 'sends request

Dim myResp As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
```

While getting the response, I am getting the issue.

Error: The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type

But if i use the same json string in postman, its working fine.

Postman code:

```
POST //api/TMS/CreateIndent HTTP/1.1
Host: 
Token: sZnYPDJE454wx7m3FMNvTFe5k6fATnKUgUE3toV5MEgB8ydfni
NTID: abcdefg
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 44836019-b3d4-c143-3c1f-5dbff2834584
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Expense"

{"PurposeId" : "4","MitraIndentId": "558","Employee":{"NTID": "abcdefg"},"Purposeothers": "null", "TravellingDetails":[{"ModeOfTravelID": "4","DepartureDate":"01/02/2022 16:23","DepartedFrom":"TD1","ArrivalDate":"02/02/2022 16:24","ArrivalAt":"TD2","BoschCost":"123","EmployeeCost":"500","IsSupportDocumnentAvailable":"true","DeviationKey":"1644404033300"}]}
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're using the same JSON string, but a different Content-Type. Yours is `application/json` while Potsman's is `multipart/form-data`

Comment: I have changed the content-type to multipart/form-data and tried it. But its not working

Comment: `multipart/form.data` **requires** the [_boundary_ directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type). You also need to format your body data accordingly. Just like in the Postman example you posted.